# Accesing a Object array in PHP and convert it to Simple Array

Tags: php, arrays, object, soap-client

I am trying to accessing a array, which is return by Soap class. But I am not able to iterate it. Please help.
$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

Variable $server_output has following return from Curl,

```
CalculatePremiumStructGeneratePolicyResponse Object
    (
        [GeneratePolicyResult] =&gt; <response><policyno></policyno><totalpremium>0</totalpremium><gc_customerid>100000000000192979</gc_customerid><transactionid>FT10317050001414</transactionid><errortext> Error In Proposal Creation. Error in User Entry:   
     Maximum Days For Past Policy Should Be 7</errortext></response>
        [result:CalculatePremiumWsdlClass:private] =&gt; 
        [lastError:CalculatePremiumWsdlClass:private] =&gt; 
        [internArrayToIterate:CalculatePremiumWsdlClass:private] =&gt; 
        [internArrayToIterateIsArray:CalculatePremiumWsdlClass:private] =&gt; 
        [internArrayToIterateOffset:CalculatePremiumWsdlClass:private] =&gt; 
    )
```

I want to convert above into simple array

```
 Array
    ( 
        [GeneratePolicyResult] =&gt; <response><policyno></policyno><totalpremium>0</totalpremium><gc_customerid>100000000000192979</gc_customerid><transactionid>FT10317050001414</transactionid><errortext> Error In Proposal Creation. Error in User Entry:   
     Maximum Days For Past Policy Should Be 7</errortext></response>
        [result] =&gt; 
        [lastError] =&gt; 
        [internArrayToIterate] =&gt; 
        [internArrayToIterateIsArray] =&gt; 
        [internArrayToIterateOffset] =&gt; 
    )
```

Please help!

Edit Note :- When I try to print gettype($server_output), it says its a string.

Comment: you cannot access private property of object array. So you need to change initial-one to get data as public property

Comment: GeneratePolicyResult is not private. At least we can access it. @Alive to Die'

Comment: try `echo $objArray->GeneratePolicyResult;`

Comment: Tried, $server_output = curl_exec ($ch);  
 echo $server_output->CalculatePremiumStructGeneratePolicyResponse->GeneratePolicyResult;, getting error Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: try this `echo $server_output->GeneratePolicyResult;`

Comment: Yes. Same Error :-  Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Edit Note :- When I try to print gettype($server_output), it says its a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of try and solutions available on Stackflow, none of works, But When i check the type of variable, it was saying string.

gettype($server_output) was printing string.

So It was a string object. SoI decided to take it as string and try to parse it.

```
$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);  
$data = explode(" [GeneratePolicyResult] =>", $server_output); 
$data = explode("[result:CalculatePremiumWsdlClass:private]", $data[1]);
```

And in this way,I have filter the "GeneratePolicyResult"

Answer (score 1):

just try

```
$array =  (array) $yourObject;
```

or use something like this(for public variables only)

```
function object_to_array($data)
{
    if (is_array($data) || is_object($data))
    {
        $result = [];
        foreach ($data as $key => $value)
        {
            $result[$key] = object_to_array($value);
        }
        return $result;
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: This is unlikely to be a viable solution in most use cases, as simply casting the object to an array can mess with the keys

Comment: @WilliamPerron you can write some function

Comment: The proposed function still has the same issue where it might mess with key names, especially for private properties

Comment: @WilliamPerron with this function you lose all private and protacted variables for sure...
first method change their names

Comment: @WilliamPerron but i think if it private, you have not to get them at all...only with special functions

Comment: Sry guys,already tried. But its keeps print the same. i had search it stackflow already

Comment: Edit Note :- When I try to print gettype($server_output), it says its a string.

Answer (score 0):

it might help you.

```
$object = CalculatePremiumStructGeneratePolicyResponse Object
    (
        [GeneratePolicyResult] =&gt; <response><policyno></policyno><totalpremium>0</totalpremium><gc_customerid>100000000000192979</gc_customerid><transactionid>FT10317050001414</transactionid><errortext> Error In Proposal Creation. Error in User Entry:   
     Maximum Days For Past Policy Should Be 7</errortext></response>
        [result:CalculatePremiumWsdlClass:private] =&gt; 
        [lastError:CalculatePremiumWsdlClass:private] =&gt; 
        [internArrayToIterate:CalculatePremiumWsdlClass:private] =&gt; 
        [internArrayToIterateIsArray:CalculatePremiumWsdlClass:private] =&gt; 
        [internArrayToIterateOffset:CalculatePremiumWsdlClass:private] =&gt; 
    );
$array = json_decode(json_encode($object), True);
```

Comment: Tried. $server_output = curl_exec ($ch); 
 $server_output =$object;
 $array = json_decode(json_encode($object), True);
   print_r($array);

Comment: Its still same. No diff. prinitng same

Comment: $server_output = curl_exec ($ch); $array = json_decode(json_encode($server_output), True);

Comment: Edit Note :- When I try to print gettype($server_output), it says its a string.